# solving a equation (floor function)

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

For what real numbers x is: ⌊2x⌋=4⌊x⌋+3?

I'm not sure how to deal with the floor functions, so I have no idea where to start. If someone could walk me through the process that would great!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\lfloor 2x\rfloor=2\lfloor x\rfloor$ or $\lfloor 2x\rfloor=2\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ depending on the fractional part. Plugging in the equation, we get

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=-\frac32$$ which is not possible or

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=-1.$$

Hence,

$$-\frac12\le x<0.$$